# HHVM crashing with segmentation fault

Tags: macos, hhvm

Everytime I call `hhvm` from the terminal I get a segmentation fault. Here's an example:

```
 ✘ evo@Evo  ~/tmp  hhvm -a
[1]    14493 segmentation fault  hhvm -a
```

This happens on Mac OS X 10.11

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug in HHVM or its OS X port. StackOverflow isn't a great place to track bugs like this. Can you [file an issue on our homebrew formula tracker](https://github.com/hhvm/homebrew-hhvm/issues)? Make sure to include all the info it asks for, as well as `brew info hhvm` and `hhvm --version` (even if the latter segfaults).